# frontend HTTPS access to http backend ngix

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, https

I have a frontend in Angular which support https,while I have a backend at port 10080 which support http.
I try a few way of reverse proxy in the ngix configuration file but it still facing the same issues.

While I try this method always get the error "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://example.com:30080/api/remoteControl/getactiveusers' from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name  _;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" always;
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

    gzip on;
    gzip_min_length 1000;
    gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
    ssl_certificate "xxx.crt";
    ssl_certificate_key "xxx.key";
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_tickets off;
    ssl_stapling off;
    
    location / {
     if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header Content-Type text/plain;
        add_header Content-Length 0;
        return 204;
    }
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' *;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';

    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
    location ~* \.(eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$ {
     add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
   }
   

}
server {
    listen       10080 ssl http2;
    server_name  _;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" always;
   ssl_certificate "xxxx.crt";
    ssl_certificate_key "xxx.key";
ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    location / {
    
        proxy_pass "http://backend:80" ;
        proxy_set_header Connection Keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;    
#            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
#           proxy_hide_header X-Frame-Options;
        proxy_buffers 4 256k;
        proxy_buffer_size 128k; 
        proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
    }
}
```

Anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Configure your backend server to generate the correct URLs for the requests (with https, without the port).

Comment: Sorry can you please explain more about this?

Answer (score 0):

Your setup has multiple issues.

First, you have two public facing nginx virtual servers, on port 443 and on port 10080. You should only have a server listening to port 443 and reverse proxy requests from there.

Second, your backend is generating content that has links like `http://example.com:10080/page`. Your backend should generate URLs like `https://example.com/page`.